# How to blit an image over a rectangle in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to blit a image over rectangle.
Here is my function for creating a rectangle.

```
def drawCell(coords,ccolor):
    #Here coords is the coordnnates (x and y axis) for rectangle
    #cclor is colour for the rectangle , white in my program.

    global score
    for coord in coords:
        x=coord['x']*cellSize
        y=coord['y']*cellSize
        makeCell=pygame.Rect(x,y,cellSize,cellSize)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,ccolor,makeCell)

        if makeCell.colliderect(foodrect):                          #If the rectangle collides with food
                                                                    #score gets added and the food is blitted
                                                                    #to a random
            foodrect.x = random.randint(0, display_width-25)
            foodrect.y = random.randint(0, display_height-25)
            score+=1
    scoredisplay(score) #Displays Score
```

This is the function call in game loop:

```
drawCell(coords,white)
```

Now what i want it to do is blit [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvNmu.png) on the rectangle so that it looks like the apple is moving (move function is different and not provided here).

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can put `gameDisplay.blit(imgname, (x,y))` after `pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,ccolor,makeCell)`

Comment: I tried that but my rectangle is blitted on top right of my image.And also this causes problem with the collision between the food image.

Comment: Sorry, I had to go to work, I notice you have marked it as answered to am assuming you solved this?

Comment: The problem still continues.